# Prove that this matrix is not diagonalizable WITHOUT determinants

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I have this matrix:

$ \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
22 & 23 & 10 & -98\\
12 & 18 & 16 & -38\\
-15 & -19 & -13 & 58 \\
6 & 7 & 4 & -25 \end{array} \right) $

and I want to show that it does NOT admit an eigenbasis. I would like to do this without finding the characteristic polynomial, since the determinant is going to be an unholy mess.. is there an easier condition for the existence of an eigenbasis that I can use?

Answer (score 3):

Denoting the matrix by $A$, you will find that multiplying yields $$A^2=A^3$$ (assuming my program is working, that is). This implies $A^2=A^3=A^4=\cdots$.

If $A$ were diagonalizable, we could write $A=S\Lambda S^{-1}$ so that $$S\Lambda^2 S^{-1}=S\Lambda^3 S^{-1}=\cdots$$ $$\Lambda^2=\Lambda^3=\cdots$$ which means all the eigenvalues must be $0$ or $1$.

We also have $\text{tr}\,\Lambda=\text{tr}\,A=2$, so that the eigenvalues are $$\lambda=0,0,1,1$$ and $\dim\ker A=2$. It shouldn't be too hard for you to show that the first three columns of $A$ are linearly independent, in which case you have the contradiction because $\dim\ker A\le 1$ in that case.

Not exactly pretty, but perhaps a bit more manageable than computing the determinant.

Comment: That's an interesting argument. Still nicer yet than a 4x4 determinant though, I'd think.